# Why are there non-decidable languages? Can anyone explain me my book's solution?

Tags: algorithm, automata, automata-theory

In my book it is says that "there are non-decidable languages" And the proof is:

> Every *algorithm* is a *word*.  Then there are only countable *algorithms*. 
>   But there are uncountable *languages* and therefore more than *algorithms*.

Why is it said that every algorithm is a word? A word is a concatenation of symbols, elements of an alphabet, then what's the relation between a word and an algorithm? Can anyone explain me that?

Comment: Are you really sure that's what the book says? "There are uncountable languages and therefore more than algorithms" isn't exactly English.

Comment: Any algorithm can be expressed (as a Turing machine, a C++ program, whatever) as a finite word using a finite alphabet.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of language theory question better suited to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @Juhana: not all books are in English.

Comment: @n.m. Certainly, but the sentence is very hard to decipher whether it's original or a translation.

Comment: @n.m. How do you know that? An algorithm is not a set of words? Thanks!

Comment: Not everyone speaks English fluently. I know I don't (please be suffering me quietly). Perhaps for this reason I don't find the sentence in question hard to understand at all.

Comment: What is your objection? Do you believe that every algorithm can be expressed as a program for a Turing machine, or not?

Comment: @AlfredaZuñiga: a word is a finite string of symbols from a fixed alphabet.

Comment: @n.m. I haven't reached this topic.

Comment: Then perhaps look ahead a bit, or just look up "Church thesis" in wikipedia or something.

Comment: @n.m. for example if my alphabet has 256 symbols. Then each program can be considered as if it were a word written in base 256, therefore the set of all programs is countable. Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct.

Comment: I see that you've reposted on [programmers.se], but for future reference, the best site for a question like this is [cs.se]. (Cc @Quentin)

Comment: Reposted as [Why are there non-decidable languages? Can anyone explain me my book's solution? on programmers.SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386539/why-are-there-non-decidable-languages-can-anyone-explain-me-my-books-solution).